# All diagonals of a rectangular board

Tags: java, diagonal

I'm struggling to think up a neat algorithm to find all diagonals of a rectangular board.

Here's a cut-down version of the `Board` object. The bit marked *NOT RIGHT YET* is where I am certain I am wrong. Currently it should correctly list all diagonals of a rectangle that is higher than it is wide and correctly find the two diagonals of a square. It gets it wrong for one that is wider than it is high.

Here's the code right now - see how no diagonals are built for the 4 X 2 board.

```
/**
 * The board.
 */
static class Board {

    /**
     * Top left corner is 0,0. Access is [y][x].
     */
    final Square[][] board;
    // The board as columns.
    final List<List<Square>> columns;
    // The dagonals.
    final List<List<Square>> diagonals;
    // For sense checking.
    final int width;
    final int height;

    // A clear square.
    private static final char Clear = ' ';

    public Board(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        board = new Square[height][];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            board[y] = new Square[width];
            // Fill it.
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                board[y][x] = new Square(x, y);
            }
        }
        // Build my columns lists.
        columns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            List<Square> column = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                column.add(board[y][x]);
            }
            columns.add(column);
        }
        // And the diagonals - NOT RIGHT YET!
        diagonals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int y = 0; y <= height - width; y++) {
            List<Square> diagonal = new ArrayList<>();
            // Left to right.
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                diagonal.add(board[y + x][x]);
            }
            diagonals.add(diagonal);
            // Right to left.
            diagonal = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                diagonal.add(board[y + x][width - 1 - x]);
            }
            diagonals.add(diagonal);
        }
    }

    public Board(int size) {
        this(size, size);
    }

    public Stream<List<Square>> asRows() {
        // Map each row to a list.
        return Arrays.stream(board).map(r -> Arrays.asList(r));
    }

    public Stream<List<Square>> asCols() {
        // Walk the columns.
        return columns.stream();
    }

    public Stream<List<Square>> asDiagonals() {
        // Walk the diagonals.
        return diagonals.stream();
    }

    public Square square(Place place) {
        return board[place.y][place.x];
    }

    /**
     * One square of the board.
     *
     * Remember that a Square is ON a board - i.e. it is a sub-object of a Board. Do not attempt to memoize Squares as they will hold a reference to their parent board.
     */
    class Square {

        // where it is on the board.
        final Place place;

        public Square(Place place) {
            this.place = place;
        }

        public Square(int x, int y) {
            this(new Place(x, y));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return place.toString();
        }

    }

    /**
     * A place on the board.
     */
    class Place {

        final int x;
        final int y;

        public Place(int x, int y) {
            // Sense check.
            if (x < 0 || x >= width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Off board: x = " + x);
            }
            if (y < 0 || y >= height) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Off board: x = " + x);
            }
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + x + "," + y + '}';
        }

    }

}

private void test(int width, int height) {
    Board board = new Board(width, height);
    System.out.println(width + " X " + height);
    for (List<Board.Square> d : board.diagonals) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

public void test() {
    test(3, 3);
    test(4, 2);
    test(2, 4);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Output

```
3 X 3
[{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}]
[{2,0}, {1,1}, {0,2}]
4 X 2
2 X 4
[{0,0}, {1,1}]
[{1,0}, {0,1}]
[{0,1}, {1,2}]
[{1,1}, {0,2}]
[{0,2}, {1,3}]
[{1,2}, {0,3}]
```

Comment: How are you defining diagonal here?

Comment: @durron597 - See posted output - all lines that span the full width/height of the rectangle that move  in the normal directions.

Comment: Width OR Height (or both)?

Comment: @durron597 - There won't be any on the long side (short side to short sine) as they would not reach all the way across - so, essentially, both.